# React-Native 0.68.2 Modals are not working - iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-modal

I upgraded react native application to **react version 17.0.1 and react-native 0.68.2.**

Modals are no longer visible on the iOS application beyond that point. I'm using the `react-native-modal: "^13.0.1"` library to create those modals.

To confirm the issue, I replaced sample modal code  [react-native-modal-example](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal) on top of my existing code. However, the problem is still present.

There is a bug reported like [this](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal/issues/679)

Therefore, I used `modal provided by react-native` instead of using `react-native-modal: "^13.0.1"` but the same problem is occurred.

Is there any solution for this?

my code as follows,

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Image, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Alert, Pressable, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal'

const login = props => {

const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles1.centeredView}>
      <Modal isVisible={true}>
        <View style={styles1.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles1.modalView}>
            <Text style={styles1.modalText}>Hello World!</Text>
            <Pressable
              style={[styles1.button, styles1.buttonClose]}
              onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}>
              <Text style={styles1.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[styles1.button, styles1.buttonOpen]}
        onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}>
        <Text style={styles1.textStyle}>Show Modal</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles1 = StyleSheet.create({
  centeredView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 22
  },
  modalView: {
    margin: 20,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 35,
    alignItems: "center",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 10,
    elevation: 2
  },
  buttonOpen: {
    backgroundColor: "#F194FF",
  },
  buttonClose: {
    backgroundColor: "#2196F3",
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  modalText: {
    marginBottom: 15,
    textAlign: "center"
  }
});
```

export default (login);

Comment: Why don't you `import  {Modal} from 'react-native'`? I use it with `"react": "17.0.2",` and `"react-native": "0.66.1",`

Comment: yah, I tried with `import  {Modal} from 'react-native'`, still the same problem. I mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

This one works!

[image]

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Modal,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
  Pressable,
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView
} from "react-native";

const Example = props => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles1.centeredView}>
      <Modal isVisible={true}>
        <View style={styles1.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles1.modalView}>
            <Text style={styles1.modalText}>Hello World!</Text>
            <Pressable
              style={[styles1.button, styles1.buttonClose]}
              onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
            >
              <Text style={styles1.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[styles1.button, styles1.buttonOpen]}
        onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}
      >
        <Text style={styles1.textStyle}>Show Modal</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Example;

const styles1 = StyleSheet.create({
  centeredView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 22
  },
  modalView: {
    margin: 20,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 35,
    alignItems: "center",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 10,
    elevation: 2
  },
  buttonOpen: {
    backgroundColor: "#F194FF"
  },
  buttonClose: {
    backgroundColor: "#2196F3"
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  modalText: {
    marginBottom: 15,
    textAlign: "center"
  }
});
```

Comment: As per my understanding, I know this should work. But sorry this not working. I'm working with `react-native 0.68.2`. I believe that's where this issue started. Anyway thank you.

Comment: The above solution is with `"react-native": "0.69.1",`

Comment: sure then I'll try this with 0.69.1, I'll let you know.